# Create csv from html pages

Tags: parsing, html-parsing

There is a website that displays a lot of data in html tables. They have paged the data so there are around 500 pages.

What is the most convenint (easy) way of getting the data in those tables and download it a CSV, on Windows?

Basically I need to write a script that does something like this but is overkilling to write in in C# and I am looking for other solutions that people with web experience use:

```
for(i=1 to 500)
   load page from http://x/page_i.html;
   parse the source and get the data in table with id='data'
   save results in csv
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a screen-scraping application once and found [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to be very useful. You could easily plop that into a Python script and parse across all the tags with the specific id you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest non-C# way I can think of is to use [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to download the page, then run [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to convert it to XML/XHTML and then transform the resulting XML to CSV with an XSLT (run with [MSXSL.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21714))

You will have to write some simple batch files and an XSLT with a basic XPath selector.

If you feel it would be easier to just do it in C#, you can use [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/Community/SgmlReader) to read the HTML DOM and do an XPath query to extract the data. It should not take more than about 20 lines of code.